# using google app engine and datastore in production

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing a central database based mobile app.  I have decided to use a cloud  service as backend as it would take care of maintenance and scaling issues. Of the two options, aws and Google cloud i have decided to go with google cloud as i read that aws has a steep learning curve (we needed to reduce development time) and gc is as good as aws. Now on google cloud i choose to use a datastore as primary db as i found that a nosql db would fit my needs (also it was cheaper). Now looking more into datastore,  they seem to have many constraints like 1 entity transaction pet sec etc, So now i am doubting my decisions.

so my questions are...

- how difficult is it to implement a db app with rest endpoints in aws
  compared to gc?
- how good is google data-store for a production app which need to
  handle any number of users without much performance degradation ?

Comment: This is quite ambiguous, advantages of cloud storage against what other option, difficult for whom and what number of users and what performance metrics are you after?

Comment: sorry for confusing , removed that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer only regards Google Appengine/Datastore.

> how good is google data-store for a production app which need to handle any number of users without much performance degradation ?

Base on my experience serving billions of page views I can say Google DataStore is extremely good in serving read request to a lot of users without degradation. Unless you don't make wrong architectural decisions you can expect consistent latency time and costs have linear relevance to your load. You should keep in mind that datastore is **distributed** database and most suited for "few writes - many reads" and you should try to pre-aggregate whatever information is needed for serving user request. Scanning a list of records sometimes OK but generally is not best idea.

The write operations should scale good as well but there could be challenges with implementations - depends on your app logic. You really should understand concepts of datastore entity groups, transactions, indexes, write costs, task queues, etc. to write fast & costs effective app.

If you get it right GAE & datastore can be very reliable and maintenance free environment.